# How to call a controller event using <f:ajax> in JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf-2

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{searchView.allSelected}" onclick="toggleChecked(this.checked)">
    <f:ajax execute="@this" event="blur" listener="#{searchController.selectRows}" />
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

I have a check box and I need to call a controller event on blur, is it the right way of calling the event through `listener`

I am getting error as does not have the property 'selectRows'

Comment: We need to see the code for the SearchController bean, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function in the bean must have this signature :

```
public void selectRows(AjaxBehaviorEvent event)
{
    ...
}
```

You are probably missing the parameter.

More info : [f:ajax](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/pdldocs/facelets/f/ajax.html)

Comment: thankyou. But I dont have any paramater on the controller side. Is it mandatory to use `AjaxBehaviorEvent` as a parameter

Comment: Yes it is, ortherwise, your function won't be found.

Comment: that works. I have one doubt `<f:ajax>`has `onevent` attribute and same thing `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox>` has `onclick` which one is called first.

Comment: Never tested but pretty sure the onclick will be first, you can check the page source code, there will be generated javascript for the onblur.